# Target.Adress is a mutiple cell range selected individually

Tags: excel, vba, worksheet

I have the following code:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Target.Address = "$N$16" Then
    Sheet3.Unprotect ""
    Call QuantityisActivated(Target)
    Sheet3.Protect ""
End If
```

End Sub

How can i use the same code for multiple `Target.Adress` for example, I want here from N16 to N30 range of cells

```
   Sub QuantityisActivated(Target)
   MsgBox "This is a sample box"
   End Sub
```

Comment: Will you always want to check against rows 16 to 30? Or might this differ?

Comment: Could you describe in more detail how this should work by adding a few examples? Adding the `QuantityisActivated` procedure would also help.

Comment: *I want here from N16 to N30* `If Target.Column=14 And Target.Row>=16 And Target.Row<=30 Then...`

Comment: Yes my rows 16 to 30 are fixed and column N is also fixed

Answer (score 0):

The following can be used to only fire the `QuantityisActivated` if cells within the range are changed:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim rng As Range, c As Range
    Set rng = Intersect(Target, Range("N16:N30"))
    If Not rng Is Nothing Then
        
        'If you want it to run on each cell withing the range..
        For Each c In rng.Cells
            Call QuantityisActivated(c)
        Next

        'Or if you want it to run once, if any cell in range is affected
        Call QuantityisActivated(rng)

    End If
End Sub
```

I've included two possible ways of dealing with the affected range - either at a cell by cell level, or as an entire range as it's not clear which you'd prefer from your question.

Comment: Yes, Both possible ways works fine. But I would use it on cell by cell